# Show error alert before complete full execution ajax post MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

This code use partial view in partial view. In Create.cshtml save record and show in AwardsHonoursReceived.cshtml but **I have face an issue the ajax is working fine save record but show error alert during saving time in db(AwardHonoursRecieved.cs) in function saveAwardHonour(tbl_EmpAwardsReceived obj)**

means ajax show error alert during execution but record save  but not do ( **success: function (data) {$("#AwardHonours").html("");            $("#AwardHonours").html(data);
                    },)**

UserController

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
      return View();
    }

    public ActionResult AwardsHonoursReceived(int? EmployeeId)
    {
        AwardRecievedViewModel model = new AwardRecievedViewModel();
        AwardHonoursRecieved.bindAwardHonourToList(model);
        ViewBag.EmployeeId = EmployeeId;
        return View(model);
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
    @Html.Action("AwardsHonoursReceived", "User")
```

AwardsHonoursReceived.cshtml

```
     @model  HRMS.Models.UserModels.AwardRecievedViewModel
 <div id="AwardHonours">
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js")"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.CreateBtnAH').click(function () {
            var EmpId = $("#EmployeeId").val();

            var url = '@Url.Action("Create", "AwardHonours")?EmpId=' + EmpId;

        $('#EditAH').html("");
        $('#EditAH').load(url);
    });
      });
</script>
        <section class="panel">

            <span id="EditAH"></span>
            <input type="hidden" id="EmployeeId" name="EmployeeId" value="@ViewBag.EmployeeId" />
            <div class="text-right"><span class="CreateBtnAH btn btn-info">Create New</span></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="adv-table">
                    <div id="dynamic-table_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline" role="grid">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <section id="no-more-tables">
                                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-responsive cf">
                                    <thead class="cf">
                                        <tr>

                                            <th>Name Of The Award</th>
                                            <th class="numeric">Organization</th>
                                            <th class="numeric">Date</th>
                                            <th class="numeric">Venue</th>
                                            <th class="numeric">Purpose Of The Order</th>
                                            <th class="numeric">Action</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        @if (Model.AwardRecievedViewModelList != null)
                                        {
                                            foreach (var item in Model.AwardRecievedViewModelList)
                                            {
                                            <tr>
                                                <td data-title="Code">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NameOfAward)</td>
                                                <td data-title="Code">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Organization)</td>
                                                <td data-title="Code">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)</td>
                                                <td data-title="Company">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Venue)</td>
                                                <td data-title="Code">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PurposeOfAward)</td>
                                                <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">
                                                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeId)
                                                    <span><a href="#" id="@item.Id"  class="EditBtnAH">
                                                        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/edit.png")" alt="edit" /></a></span>
                                                    <span><span id="@item.Id"  class="DeleteBtnAH">
                                                        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/delete.png")" alt="Delete" /></span></span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="6">NO Records</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        }
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </section>
                        </div>



                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <div class="dataTables_info" id="dynamic-table_info">Showing 1 to 10 of 57 entries</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_bootstrap pagination">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="prev disabled"><a href="#">← Previous</a></li>
                                        <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                                        <li class="next"><a href="#">Next → </a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

AwardHonours  Controller

```
    public ActionResult Create(int? EmpId)
    {
        ViewBag.Emp = EmpId;
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(AwardRecievedViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (HatronEntities context = new HatronEntities())
            {
                tbl_EmpAwardsReceived obj = new tbl_EmpAwardsReceived();
                obj.NameOfAward = model.NameOfAward;
                obj.Organization = model.Organization;
                obj.Date = model.Date;
                obj.Venue = model.Venue;
                obj.PurposeOfAward = model.PurposeOfAward;
                obj.EmployeeId = model.EmployeeId;
                AwardHonoursRecieved.saveAwardHonour(obj);
            }
            var msg = "Created Successfully";
            return RedirectToAction("AwardsHonoursReceived", "User", new { msg = msg, EmployeeId = model.EmployeeId });
        }
        else {
            var msg = "Not Saved";
            return RedirectToAction("AwardsHonoursReceived", "User", new { msg = msg }); }
    }
```

create.cshtml

```
 <div class="panel-body">
<form class="form-horizontal bucket-form" id="myformAH">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name Of Award</label>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NameOfAward, new { id = "", @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NameOfAward)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Organization</label>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Organization, new { id = "", @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Organization)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Date</label>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { id = "", @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Venue</label>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Venue, new { id = "", @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Venue)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Purpose Of Award</label>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PurposeOfAward, new { id = "", @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PurposeOfAward)
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="EmployeeId" value="@ViewBag.Emp" />

    <div class="form-group has-error">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label col-lg-3" for="inputError">&nbsp;</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <input type="hidden" id="SubModuleId" name="SubModuleId" value="@ViewBag.SubModuleId" />
            <input type="submit" value="Save & Exit" class="submitAH btn btn-info" />
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="cancelAH btn btn-info" />

        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")">   </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.cancelAH').click(function () {
        $('#EditAH').html("");
    });
    $('.submitAH').click(function () {
        var Form = $("#myformAH").serialize();
        if ($("#myformAH").valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/AwardHonours/Create",
                type: 'POST',
                data: Form,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#AwardHonours").html("");
                    $("#AwardHonours").html(data);
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    return false;
                }

            });
        }
    });
   });
</script>
```

AwardHonoursRecieved.cs

```
    public static int saveAwardHonour(tbl_EmpAwardsReceived obj)
    {
        int status = 0;
        int lastID = 0;
        using (HatronEntities context = new HatronEntities())
        {
            //==== Check for duplicacy.
            // status = context.tbl_EmpPromotion.Count(r => r.Designation == obj.Designation);
            //if (status == 0) //==== means no similar Relation exists save Relation. 
           // {
                // Fetch Id of last record from table
                var result = (from c in context.tbl_EmpAwardsReceived.OrderByDescending(u => u.Id)
                              select new { Id = c.Id }).FirstOrDefault();
                if (result != null)
                {
                    lastID = Convert.ToInt32(result.Id);
                }
                obj.Id = lastID + 1;
                context.tbl_EmpAwardsReceived.Add(obj);
                context.SaveChanges();
           // }
        }
        return status;
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Means ajax show error alert during execution , record save successfully  but not go in succes part in ajax for update the list LIKE :  **success: function (data) {$("#AwardHonours").html("");            $("#AwardHonours").html(data);
                    },)**